# Defaults in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, default-value

Can we have multiple default values according to conditions stated for each default in postresql?

Like Can we have different defaults according to a  entry of a column for each insert.

Comment: Please update your question with examples of what you are trying to achieve. At the moment your question doesn’t really explain anything

Comment: A single column has exactly one default value.

Comment: _"Can we have multiple default values according to conditions stated for each default in postresql?"_ - if you did then they wouldn't be "defaults" then, would they?

Comment: You can do it by create view....

Answer (score 1):

A column default cannot depend on other columns in the table. You probably need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.